# Add and convert an Array of a different data type into a List

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have an array `CustomClass[] classes`. I want an easy way to add it to `List<String>`, for this I have to call the method `CustomClass#getName()` which returns a `String`.

This is how it's supposedly done:

```
    for (CustomClass class : classes) {
        list.add(class.getName());
    }
```

Is there a one-line way to do it?

Comment: This will throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using [`Arrays.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(numbers)
                          .map(String::valueOf)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Which will stream the `Array`, convert it to a `String` and then collect it to a `List<String>`

---

Or now that you've edited your question to include a class:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.stream(classes)
                          .map(Foo::getName)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Assuming your class is called `Foo` and has a `getName` method

Answer (score 2):

For the modified question, basically the same answer:

```
Arrays.stream(classes).map(clz -> clz.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```